# PHP AJAX POST/GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I almost finished my little project but i have a problem with reading data sent to server.

```
function main() {
jQ(document).on("keyup", "form input", function () {
        var data = new FormData();
        var value = jQ(this).val();
        data.append('value', value);
        console.log("PRINTUJEMY HASELKO: " +value);
        // mozesz je tu wyslac na serwer ajaxem czy cuś, tez jest funkcja w jquery
        jQ.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "http://www.mywebsite/result.php",
            data    : data,

            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

        });
    })
    .keyup();
```

I attaching a php file :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$x = ( $_GET['value'] );
echo "PHP Zaladowane".$x;
$q = intval($_GET['$value']);

if

( $_REQUEST["value"] )
{
   $name = $_REQUEST['value'];

   echo "Welcome $x $q". value. $q;
}

function cors() {

    // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

    echo "You have CORS!";
}
?>
```

I can see in console the success message "PRINTUJEMY HASELKO: ddd
jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://www.mywebsite/result.php"."

My website is not showing anything (Values from inputs). 
Have a good night. :)

Comment: i guess $_REQUEST["value"] isn't evaluating to true. 
anyway, add to the top, after the header() call
var_dump('$_GET',$_GET,'$_POST',$_POST,'$_COOKIE',$_COOKIE,'$_FILES',$_FILES);  and stop using $_REQUEST :o

Comment: Your var_dump is not working. Thank you for answer

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript code looks like it's making a POST request to your PHP, in which case you should use `$_POST` rather than `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.

Make sure you sanitize any data that comes from there before you use it though, otherwise you're opening yourself to injection attacks.

Comment: actually, $_REQUEST should work, its a combination of $_POST, $_GET, and $_COOKIE , iirc ... but you should never use $_REQUEST, as you can't really know where the data is coming from, without asking ini_get('request_order '), AND you can't know if something has been overwritten, without checking with ALL 3 OF THEM, $_POST, $_GET,$_COOKIE, so things can be silently overwritten... its really not worth it, don't use $_REQUEST, its bad. imo.

Comment: I changed GET on POST, deleted REQUEST and i have same thing like before. Thank you for answer.